# Geting error when trying to call API (Content Security Policy)

Tags: angular, api, httprequest, content-security-policy, httphandler

Trying to start `get` function from deployed website and get this error:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v2/xxx/search.php?s=apple' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http://*.google-analytics.com http://www.googletagmanager.com https://*.google.com https://*.google-analytics.com https://*.googletagmanager.com https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com https://authedmine.com https://az743702.vo.msecnd.net https://sentry.io ws://localhost:4200". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

While running website on localhost server everything was working fine.

Added this `meta tag` to my `index.html` and still getting the same error message.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, at first I added meta tag for my `index.html` page and it didin't worked.
After that I created `interceptor`, to add headers to my `get` function.
More about interceptors you can read at https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Still not working.
Then I figured out that in my server.ts file there is these lines of code:

```
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: AppConfig.cspDirectives
}));
```

. More info about `helmet`:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet

Then in my app.module providers section there is assigned `{provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: AppConfig}` configuration.

Here is how app.config.ts file looks like now:

```
import {InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('app.config');

export const AppConfig: any = {
  cspDirectives: {
    defaultSrc: [
      '\'self\'',
      'http://*.google-analytics.com',
      'http://www.googletagmanager.com',
      'https://*.google.com',
      'https://*.google-analytics.com',
      'https://*.googletagmanager.com',
      'https://*.gstatic.com',
      'https://*.googleapis.com',
      'https://authedmine.com',
      'https://az743702.vo.msecnd.net',
      'https://sentry.io',
      'https://www.themealdb.com/',
      'ws:<my-webpage-url>',
    ],
    styleSrc: [
      '\'self\'',
      '\'unsafe-inline\'',
      'https://*.googleapis.com'
    ],
    scriptSrc: [
      '\'self\'',
      '\'unsafe-inline\'',
      'http://*.googletagmanager.com',
      'https://*.google-analytics.com'
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check what CSP response headers your deployed website are sending. Adding a meta tag can only restrict the total set of CSPs.

Also you are trying to connect to ''. If your intended URL is white listed in the CSP but for some reason comes out blank, that could be the reason it is failing.